# I believe this patent application has prior art - US2013/0220295

Tags: prior-art, us20130220295

I believe this patent application has prior art and is not patentable.

https://www.google.com.au/patents/US20130220295?dq=jack+kingsley&hl=en&sa=X&ei=18qBUpvgIObwiAfy2YG4Dg&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAA

People have been modding paintball guns to accept shells for a long time and i dont believe this should be allowed to be patented. do you need to see some prior art?

Comment: Posting here is not directly addressing either the inventor or the USPTO examiner.

Answer (score 1):

In examining patent applications the USPTO examiner can not just say "I think this has been done before". Preferably they find documents that describe what the applicant is claiming and in their rejection explain where in the document the specific aspects of the claims are covered.

Answer (score 0):

1. **First, you need to figure out if this is really worth your energy.** Why are you concerned about this patent application? If you want to become a patent crusader, you might consider answering some prior art requests on here, or helping out on a crowdsourced prior art search site. Googling that phrase will get you more info.

   If you are a paintball enthusiast doing this because you think this patent could be used to suppress competition amongst manufacturers of paintball equipment, understand that a minority of patent applications ever become patents and an even smaller minority of those patents ever get asserted. If the prior art is as abundant as you seem to think it is, the odds of both of those things go down even more.

   **tl;dr**: it's pretty unlikely that anyone will be sued over this patent application.
2. **As George White suggested, you need to track down some actual prior art.** Look for things like articles, other patent applications, or product manuals, that (a) describes what the application claims and (b) were published (posted on the internet) before the priority date of this application (Feb 27, 2012). Post the 3 most detailed things you find on here and see if anyone will give you their thoughts on their substance.
3. **Follow George White's other guide on third party prior art submissions:** [I have prior art for a pending patent. What should I do?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3599/i-have-prior-art-for-a-pending-patent-what-should-i-do/3600#3600)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. Thanks for supporting my inputs. In AP and all other SE sites we try to separate comments about a question from answers to a question. I understand that the OP's original post wasn't really a question so that is hard to do in this case.